# Find minimum of List of Lists in R

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a list of lists. I want to get the `order_number` with the smallest `distance`.

Here's my list of lists.

```
d <- list( list(distance = 450, order_number = 12), 
list(distance = 930, order_number = 99), 
list(distance = 100, order_number = 34))
```

The `order_number` with the smallest `distance` is 34.

Here's what I have so far.

```
sapply(d, function(x) d[which.min(d[[x]]$distance,]$order_number))
```

which gives a syntax error.

Comment: `which.min(sapply(d, \`[[\`, "order_number"))` gives you the index of `d` that contains the (first) minimum value.

Comment: Change `"order_number"` to `"distance"`

Comment: `d[[which.min(sapply(d, '[[', "distance"))]]$order_number`. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(d, unlist)))
df$order_number[df$distance==min(df$distance)]
```

This returns the `order_number` where distance is minimum

Comment: You need a `data.frame` to demonstrate the minimum value of a list?

Comment: Using this you get all `order_number`s that share the same minimum value, not only the first.

Comment: Dear @R.Schifini, how you could adapt your example so that it also allows you to extract the index from the list, ie. I am interested in knowing the minimum value and the index of the list it is in.

Comment: @rral Try `which(df$distance==min(df$distance))`.